# Bug on importing Luis version (model already exist)

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I am trying to import LUIS version to my LUIS app.
I did it many times in the past but today, it jsut doesn't want whatever versionor app I try, the message always says BadArgument: The models: { entity_1, entity_2} already exist in the specified application version.

The problem appears also with old version I already imported with no problem in the past.

Did anybody have the same problem and find a solution?

Comment: did you modify the json version of your app manually before importing it?

Comment: No I don't. I also try with an old version that worked in the past and it haven't work neither. Even in a completly new app, it doesn't works :s

Comment: Is your exported model secret or could you share it?

Comment: It's a model for my client, so I can't share it :/ But maybe you can tell me what element in the model I should pay attention to ?

Comment: Have a look to the definition of your entities. But it's really hard to help without having a look to the export file. Some things you can try: remove all the entities (definition and items in utterances) from the file and see if the import is working

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem !

I had **roles** in one of my entity that had the same names of **entities**. It was not a problem before so I never notice it... :(

Thank you @FerdinandFejskid and @NicolasR !!